# Count array objects that meet a condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following code that allows me to count the number of objects that have a value, I was wondering if there is a better approach? or shorter?

```js
const requestArr = [{
  "name": "created",
  "value": "2023-01-01"
}, {
  "name": "rm",
  "value": "Test"
}, {
  "name": "st",
  "value": ""
}, {
  "name": "status",
  "value": ""
}, {
  "name": "it",
  "value": ""
}]

var i = 0
for (const key of Object.keys(requestArr)) {

  if (requestArr[key].value) {
    i++

  }

}
console.log(i)
```

Comment: unlikely, iterating over a set of items and adding to a counter variable is simple and fast, otherwise solutions would look like building additional arrays with filtration just to perform a count on it. What you have is suitable.

Comment: requestArr isn't an object, so using Object.keys on it is weird.  You could just do `for (const element of requestArr)` and then see if element.value exists.

Comment: ```requestArr.filter(i=>!!i.value).length```

Comment: `requestArr.filter(i=>!!i.value).length` this is it, it works I was trying the following that didnt work `Object.keys(requestArr).filter(function(o) { return o.value != "" }).length`

Comment: You don't need the `!!` since filter works on truthy values not just booleans.